# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unsupported style: 4'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using this code to create   top right bar button and perform a action in ios objective C.

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem  alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self  action:@selector(addAppliance)]; 
    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

But showing this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',`reason: 'Unsupported style: 4'

First throw call stack:

```
(  
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess   + 350 
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw   + 48 
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cc88    
+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88 
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff258b8bd2 
  -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] 
  + 191   
    4   UIKitCore                         
    0x00007fff48d70f87 +[_UIBarButtonItemData standardItemDataForStyle:] 
  + 539  
    5   UIKitCore                     
        0x00007fff4828b26f -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS _  
 computeTextAttributes] + 216 
    6   UIKitCore                            
  0x00007fff4828b173 -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisual  
 ProviderIOS  _computeTextAttributesForBarButtonItem:]  
  + 371  
    7   UIKitCore                          
   0x00007fff4828eef7 -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisual 
 ProviderIOS configureButton:fromBarButtonItem:] + 223  
    8   UIKitCore                           
  0x00007fff4828ce8d -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisual  
  ProviderIOS configureButton:withAppearanceDelegate:fromBarItem:] 
  + 114 
    9   UIKitCore                          
   0x00007fff4828796f -  
  [_UIButtonBarButton _configureFromBarItem:appearanceDelegate 
  :isBackButton:] + 83  
    10  UIKitCore                 
          0x00007fff4828750b -[_UIButtonBarButton configureFromBarItem:withAppearanceDelegate:] + 53 
    11  UIKitCore                   
        0x00007fff48283a27 -[_UIButtonBar _updatedViewForBarButtonItem:withView:]
 + 456  
    12  UIKitCore                     
      0x00007fff48281d02 __32-[_UIButtonBar _newGroupLayout:]_block_invoke + 82
    13  UIKitCore                         
  0x00007fff48291708 -[_UIButtonBarItemLayout _updateItemView] + 53 
    14  UIKitCore                       
    0x00007fff48291ce9 -[_UIButtonBarItemLayout _configure] + 39 
    15  UIKitCore                       
    0x00007fff482907a5 -[_UIButtonBarLayout configure] + 51 
    16  UIKitCore                        
   0x00007fff48290908 -[_UIButtonBarLayout addLayoutViews:] + 49 
    17  UIKitCore                          
   0x00007fff48293dd3 -[_UIButtonBarItemGroupLayout _iterateConfiguredLayouts:]
 + 228          
    18  UIKitCore                          
 0x00007fff48293eaf -[_UIButtonBarItemGroupLayout _addLayoutViews:]
 + 111           
    19  UIKitCore            
 0x00007fff4829086c - 
 [_UIButtonBarLayout 
 addLayoutViews:layoutGuides:constraintsToActivate:
constraintsToDeactivate:] + 111 
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48282424 -[_UIButtonBar _layoutBar] + 1768
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4828637e -[_UIButtonBarStackView updateConstraints] + 48
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490b0afa -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 489
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490b10c8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 1187
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490b0f62 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 829
    25  Foundation                          0x00007fff25aa5778 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 84
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490b186a __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 85
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490b0077 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 104
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490b13c5 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 154
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff490b22e4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 393
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4917e9f1 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1334
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4830a32d -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPush _prepareContentView] + 204
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4830c36d -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPush prepare] + 106
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4831bd7c -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _performAnimationWithTransitionCompletion:transition:] + 2221
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482bd813 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItem:transitionAssistant:] + 568
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482bcf76 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItemUsingCurrentTransition:] + 366
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482bd0e2 -[UINavigationBar pushNavigationItem:animated:] + 179
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482b7523 -[UINavigationBar _performUpdatesIgnoringLock:] + 45
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482bd1d9 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItem:transition:] + 133
    39  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48549776 __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke + 457
    40  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff485498ed __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke.1801 + 114
    41  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48544c46 __98-[UINavigationController _shouldSkipHostedRefreshControlUpdateSchedulingDeferredUpdateIfNecessary]_block_invoke + 16
    42  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff485467ef -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1348
    43  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48547954 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    44  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48528924 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 217
    45  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49193678 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2478
    46  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4c6398 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
    47  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4cc523 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 523
    48  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4d7bba _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 80
    49  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b420c04 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEd + 324
    50  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4545ef _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 649
    51  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c84fc8 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 104
    52  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48d32ab0 __handleEventQueueInternal + 7506
    53  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48d28fb9 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 88
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0d31 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_ + 17
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0c5c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0434 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    57  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b02e __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    58  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9a944 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    59  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38ba6c1a GSEventRunModal + 139
    60  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c8b9ec UIApplicationMain + 1605
    61  GasChecker                          0x000000010099e5b7 main + 55
    62  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff51a231fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Tried to fix the formatting. Please check if it's ok now and for the future please spend a little bit more time with formatting your questions

Comment: Sure Sir, Please help me

Comment: Try this: `UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target: self action: @selector(addAppliance)];`